# Emount adapter question

Tags: sony, minolta

I have a Minolta 50mm AF lens, a-mount, that I'd like to use on a Sony a6000 e-mount. Is there a reasonably priced adapter out there? Also is the Minolta MD/MC lens an a-mount?

Comment: What research have you done?

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by reasonably-priced.

The Sony adapters you can use are the LA-EA2 or the LA-EA4. The difference between the two is that the LA-EA2 only has APS-C coverage, while the LA-EA4 has full-frame coverage. For your use case - on an APS-C camera - either will work. (Both of these adapters have an in-built focus motor, required to power the autofocus in screw-drive A-mount lenses.)

The Minolta MD/MC mount is not the same as A-mount. But you can also get adapters to use these manual focus lenses on E-mount cameras. In this case, there is no official Sony adapter; you will be looking at third-party brands such as Novoflex.

Answer (score -1):

You can find best and low rate Sony adapter for Minolta 50mm AF lens at [https://www.amazon.com/Minolta-50mm-f1-7-AF-Lens/dp/B000EHMGBA](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000EHMGBA). For more  information you can check [Sony A6000 manual.](http://guideusermanual.com/product-name-a6000-manual&po=26394&lang=English)